# How to get the executable name when accessing the program's resources through HTML?

Tags: c++, html, mfc, resources

I have a HtmlView inside my MFC program where I display some data in HTML form. The HTML makes use of some resources included within the executable file, so, in general, my HTML files include some things like:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="res://MyProgram.exe/JS/IDR_JQUERY"></script>
```

or

```
<img src="res://MyProgram.exe/JPG/PROGRAMLOGO"/>
```

Problem is, if the user changes the program name from MyProgram.exe to something else, the HTML no longer works properly.

I am using `CHtmlView::LoadFromResource` to load the HTML file. I was already able to change the HTML at run time for the body section using this function:

```
BOOL DHtmlView::PutBodyContent(LPSTR lpstrContent)
{
 //check if HtmlDocument initialized
 if( m_pHtmlDoc2)
 {
  HRESULT hr = S_OK;
  IHTMLElement *pBodyElement;
  //get body element
  hr=m_pHtmlDoc2->get_body( &pBodyElement);
  //put content to body element
  _bstr_t pbBody( lpstrContent);
  hr=pBodyElement->put_innerHTML( pbBody);

  if( hr==S_FALSE) return FALSE;
  else return TRUE;
 }
 else return FALSE;
}
```

but I can't seem to find a way to do the same with the head section.

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time meddling with `IHTMLElement`, I found a much easier way to do it. Since my HTML file is itself inside the program resources, I found I could just do relative references. So my examples turned to:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../JS/IDR_JQUERY"></script>

<img src="../JPG/PROGRAMLOGO"/>
```

Comment: Excellent!  This works fine, provided that the location of things don't alter.  Otherwise, fair game :)

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the name of the executable using the API call [`::GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28VS.85%29.aspx) and strip away the path.

Reference the name of the executable in your HTML using some kind of an escape-sequence like "$(FileName)":

```
<img src="res://$(FileName)/JPG/PROGRAMLOGO"/>
```

Prior to setting the contents of the HTML document, replace all occurences of your escape sequence with the result of your GetModuleFileName() API call.

Comment: Tks, the problem is that I can't find a way to put the changed data in the CHtmlView... as far as I know it can only load directly from the resource file (using LoadFromResource).

Comment: Overide CHTMLView::OnDocumentComplete, and from there iterate the DOM of the IHTMLDocument2, modifying attributes as need be.